# Solspace's user add-on, allow for custom fields in the registration form?

Tags: solspace, solspace-user

The user add-on, does that allow us to set up custom fields to be used in the new member registration form?

Fields such as: twitter username, favorite color, etc?

Or is that something we can't do during the new member registration form and that would have to be done when the user edits their profile?

I know you can set custom fields for a user's profile, but I am wondering about custom fields in the registration form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any custom member fields you create in the admin should be available for use as fields on the registration form: http://www.solspace.com/docs/user/register/#form_fields . You can also use their [select tag pair](http://www.solspace.com/docs/user/register/#select_your_custom_field) for custom fields:

```
<select name="your_custom_field">
{select_your_custom_field}
    <option value="{value}">{value}</option>
{/select_your_custom_field}
</select>
```